# Replace content with content from file in ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I replace the content in a div, with the content in my file that i'm using in ng-include?

```
<div id="fish">
  <button ng-click="getPartial()">

  <div ng-model="include"></div>
</div>
$scope.getPartial = function()
{
        $scope.include = "partials/invoices/editcustinvoice.html";
};
```

How can I replace the the content inside fish, with my content in editcustinvoice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want include content in your view you need to use ng-include directive instead ng-model please see example here :http://plnkr.co/edit/N4KqRaro3CiOkzKpwEUZ?p=preview
 or read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.getPartial = function()
{
        $scope.include = "editcustinvoice.html";
};
});
```

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <button ng-click="getPartial()">get partial</button>
    <div ng-include="include"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: What is:     <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>?

Comment: @user500468 sorry for confusing you that was just how plnkr adding reference to scripts

Comment: now here was difference:  <div ng-include="include"></div>

Comment: @user500468 is everything fine ?

Comment: This is a **code only** answer and should have some explanation to it. People shouldn't have to guess at what the differences are

Comment: @sylwester: Hi, thank you for you answer. Im using ng-include, but It don't replace the content, with my content in the file that is being included. I want to replace the content, with the content in my file that I include.

Comment: @user500468 more likely path to you template is wrong please see here you http://plnkr.co/edit/N4KqRaro3CiOkzKpwEUZ?p=preview that should helps you. Try "/partials/invoices/editcustinvoice.html" or "./partials/invoices/editcustinvoice.html"

Comment: @user500468 you're welcome, I will appreciate if you can mark question as solved